# How can I handle spaces in file names when using xargs on find results?

Tags: find, grep, pipe, xargs

One of my common practices is to perform greps on all files of a certain type, e.g., find all the HTML files that have the word "rumpus" in them. To do it, I use

```
find /path/to -name "*.html" | xargs grep -l "rumpus"
```

Occasionally, `find` will return a file with a space in its name such as `my new file.html`. When `xargs` passed this to `grep`, however, I get these errors:

```
grep: /path/to/bad/file/my: No such file or directory
grep: new: No such file or directory
grep: file.html: No such file or directory
```

I can see what's going on here: either the pipe or the `xargs` is treating the spaces as delimiters between files. For the life of me, though, I can't figure out how to prevent this behavior. Can it be done with `find` + `xargs`? Or do I have to use an entirely different command?

Answer (score 34, accepted):

Use

```
find ... -print0 | xargs -0 ...
```

e.g.

```
find /path/to -name "*.html"  -print0 | xargs -0  grep -l "rumpus"
```

from the find man page

```
-print0
          True; print the full file name on the standard  output,  followed
          by  a  null  character  (instead  of  the  newline character that
          ‘-print’ uses).  This allows file names that contain newlines  or
          other  types  of  white space to be correctly interpreted by pro-
          grams that process the find output.  This option  corresponds  to
          the ‘-0’ option of xargs.
```

Answer (score 18):

You do not need to use **xargs**, because **find** can execute commands itself. When doing this, you do do not have to worry about the shell interpreting characters in the name.

```
find /path/to -name "*.html" -exec grep -l "rumpus" '{}' +
```

from the find man page

> -exec command {} +
>   This  variant  of the -exec action runs the specified
>   command on the selected files, but the
>   command line is built  by  appending
>   each  selected file name at the end;
>   the total number of invocations of the
>   command will  be  much  less  than 
>   the  number  of matched  files.   The
>   command line is built in much the same
>   way that xargs builds its command
>   lines.  Only one instance of  `{}' is 
>   allowed  within the command.  The
>   command is executed in the starting
>   directory.

Comment: I would upvote this but I have non left for today - I'll do it tomorrow.

Comment: @Iain - there you go (I agree, by the way).

Comment: Just using find you still miss out on features of xargs, plus you have to deal with silly quoting rules.  See the -P argument to xargs if you have more than one core / CPU.

Comment: What do the single quotes do in `'{}'` ? I don’t see any difference in results when I exclude them.

Answer (score 7):

If find and xarg versions on your system doesn't support `-print0` and `-0` switches (for example AIX find and xargs) you can use this:

```
find /your/path -name "*.html" | sed 's/ /\\ /g' | xargs grep -l "rumpus"
```

Here sed will take care of escaping the spaces for xargs.

Comment: This helped me because I had a long list of file names that was difficult to produce that I used several times. I can't just go `find` them all again.