# how to wrap the command1 return strings with single/double quotation marks (\'or\") to feed to the next command2?

Tags: linux, command, xargs

For example, I want to use mplayer to play the music of several dirs, type like this in bash:

$find './l_music/La Scala Concert 03 03 03'  './l_music/Echoes  The Einaudi Collection' './l_music/Ludovico Einaudi - The Royal Albert Hall Concert [2 CD] (2010)' -name '*.mp3' | xargs mplayer

Well, You Know, the find command return path, which dir and file always have space, the pipe right command mplayer do not accept those mp3 path.

I think that if wrap the find return strings with single/double quotation marks (\'or\") to feed to mplayer, the problem will be solved.

But how can I do to solve the problem just use bash command, do not use bash or perl scripts, while can give me one perl line command use Perl Command-Line Options.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the `-print0` option in *find* which will separate the filenames using a null character instead of a space.

In *xargs* use `-0` which tells it that the filesnames it will receive as input are separated by nulls.

Your example command then becomes:

```
find './l_music/La Scala Concert 03 03 03' './l_music/Echoes The Einaudi Collection' './l_music/Ludovico Einaudi - The Royal Albert Hall Concert [2 CD] (2010)' -name '*.mp3' -print0 | xargs -0 mplayer
```

See also: [How can I handle spaces in file names when using xargs on find results?](https://serverfault.com/questions/268368/how-can-i-handle-spaces-in-file-names-when-using-xargs-on-find-results)

Comment: gosh!! ^_^ why the mplayer is out of key control after use the command?

Comment: @infantcoder: I can't say. That would be a question better answered on http://superuser.com or http://unix.stackexchange.com.